# Prove that $kG$ has a central nilpotent element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$k$ is a field of characteristic $p$.

$G$ is a finite group, and $p$ divides its order.

Book's outline solution

> If $f=\sum_{x\ni G}x$, then $fy=yf(y\in G)$ and $f^2=|G|f=0$.

First of all, shouldn't it be $x\in G$?

Second, how do we know that $fy=yf$? All I know is that (by definition) multiplication is commutative in the field $k$.

I also don't understand the $f^2=|G|f=0$ part. Ok, as $|G|$ is a multiple of $p$, then $|G|f$ is $0$. But...why is $f^2=|G|f$?

Comment: First question: Yes.

Comment: Second question: Check that $fy = yf = f$.

Comment: Third question: See the answer to the second question.

Comment: Hint: if you list all the elements of $G$ and multiply each element in the list by $y$ on the left or the right, what does that do to the list?

Comment: Ok, got it - it stays the same.

Comment: So when we do $f^2$, we are summing $f$ with itself once for every element in the group, and hence we get $|G|f$.

Comment: Also, just checking: as there is a nilpotent element in the centre, the Jacobson Radical is non-zero and hence $kG$ is not semisimple, right?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt: Yes, exactly.